# Solving $\sin(x^2)=\sin(x)^2$ (without transcendence of $\pi$)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is it possible to find all solutions by analytic means? Maybe even without using the fact that $\pi$ does not satisfy a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients?

Comment: If if we didn't know that beforehand, we'd know it afterwards. Hence any solution is at least as complicated as a proof of that property of $\pi$.

Comment: Well, we wouldn't get full transcendence afterwards, just that $\pi$ does not satisfy a quadratic.

Comment: Upon second reading - how are all real solutions "quickly found"? I don't see anything better than numerical methods

Comment: You're right, I edit.

Answer (score 2):

We are in a case of relationship $(f \circ g - g \circ f)(x)=0$ with $f = \sin$ and $g:x \rightarrow x^2$. That may or not have in interest. In order to have an idea a general position of roots, we have plotted curves of $f$ and $g$ (we have limited the plot to the first quadrant because both functions are even). There is an infinite number of roots for which a general formula probably does not exist.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

**First way**

Maybe one method could be the usage of Taylor Series.

Indeed let's try to a low order:

$$\sin x^2 \approx x^2$$

$$\sin^2(x)\approx x^2$$

Which means $$x^2 = x^2$$ not very useful since every real number could be solution of that identity and it won't obviously work. We need more terms.

With more terms, you'll find

$$\sin x^2 \approx x^2 - \frac{x^6}{6}$$

$$\sin^2(x) \approx x^2 - \frac{x^4}{3}$$

thence you have to solve

$$-\frac{x^6}{6} + \frac{x^4}{3} = 0$$

$$-\frac{x^4}{3}\left(\frac{x^2}{2} - 1\right) = 0$$

thence besides the trivial solution $x = 0$ you have $$x^2 = 2$$

More terms more solutions. But surely you won't get them all I guess..

Also this is a numerical method so it's really approximative. But it's a try like everyotherelse

Comment: @MiloBrandt Now your comment is useless! ^^

Comment: I think second order approximations are far from accurate here.

Comment: @Vim Not *that* inaccurate: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qb7ypzssvf ($\sqrt 2 \approx 1.364...$)

Comment: I know.. I mean it's not perfect, it's just an approximation. We should need more anymore terms, like $x^{12}$ and who knows..

Comment: The (obvious) numerical method to solve the polynomial equations given by truncating the Taylor series anywhere is very unlikely to stumble across exact closed-form solutions (which are what the question is asking for).

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD By the way thank you for having made me to know that site! Cool!!